# how to change events in textbox binding source from contain to exact in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, binding, textbox

how to change events in textbox from contain to exact in vb.net?.
note : I use visual studio 2010
thanks
jack

```
       Dim source1 As New BindingSource()
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            source1.Filter = ""
            Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
        Else
            source1.Filter = "CODE like  '%' + '" & TextBox1.Text & "' + '%' "
            Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I have completely no idea what you are asking...

Comment: Do you mean `source1.Filter = "CODE = '" + TextBox1.Text" + "'";`? Is `CODE` actually a string Type?

Comment: @Jimi , 
yes it's right, and the type is string